# The human organism knows what we have to eat?

Tags: human-biology, vitamins

My mother has told that if your organism needs a vitamin, you want fruits include that vitamin. For example you have lack of C-vitamin you would like to eat lemon. Is there any explanation for it, or just it is a myth? The human organism knows that what we have to eat?

Comment: Probably organism not organisation

Comment: @ChrisStronks Please don't recommend Skeptics unless you explain the requirements of the site. Especially the notability rules, which otherwise tend to get most questions by new users closed.

Comment: @MadScientist - I have removed my comments. What are notability rules? And which requirements do you mean? those from Bio.SE or Skeptics.SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean organism, not organisation, it's not entirely false that cravings can be driven by deficiencies. In the case of the eating disorder pica, where a person eats non-food items like dirt and clay, can be caused by iron deficiency ([Source](http://www.academia.edu/202338/Pica_An_Update)). However, that article also suggests the possibility that pica *causes* iron deficiency by causing the person to eat items that lower iron absorption. So, my answer to your question is, maybe.